# Server script code can not run query with a variable as parameter

Tags: node.js, database, psql

I built a server and a database. My question is about an issue regarding a query i run on the database:

```
app.get('/api/plan/download/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {rows} = await client.query('select * from nova_schema.files where user_id = ' + req.id + ';');
        res.send(rows);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log('fail' + ex);
        res.send('fail' + ex);
    }
});
```

throws an error "failerror: column "undefined" does not exist"

but this works:

```
const {rows} = await client.query('select * from nova_schema.files where user_id = 1;');
```

I am a newbie and trying to learn. What might be the issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing `req.params.id`

simply change the line to

```
const {rows} = await client.query('select * from nova_schema.files where user_id = ' + req.params.id + ';');
```